# telegram bot API how to create auto massage when user click start

Tags: javascript, api, bots, telegram

I create  telegram bot.  How to create auto massage when user click start
like this "THanks for connection to our bot".

2. Is it possible to create an algorithm by which the user will be able to connect to the Bot from my site without going to the telegram and without pressing /START.
   As a result, I need to send notifications to the user in telegram

at this moment i have algorithm

1. the user go to  my  telegram BOT and presses the start
2. after - comeback to my site, presse the button-trigger "connect to the bot" and i go to url telegram API (getUpdates) and the userID in the telegram to which I will send a message.

object i get from this url
https://api.telegram.org/bot/getUpdates?offset=-1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20fng.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

1. I don't know which library you use. So you can check this [page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) with examples of bots for your language and library.
2. Unfortunately the user won't be able to connect to the Bot from your site without going to the Telegram.

Comment: thanks, i use php, so i need to write code on other server or i can to do this by telegram Menu?

Comment: No, you need to write code for bot where you will be handle all updates. Probaly you can do this on the same server.